# How to pass data from a view controller to a model?

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a project that has a Create Account page represented by a view controller called CreateNewAccount and a class of the same name which accompanies it. There are four values that are inputted into this view controller: 1) firstName, 2) lastName, 3) username, and 4) password. This view controller also has a "Create Account" button that when pressed, should transfer the String values inputted in the 4 inputs to a new class called UInfoRetrieveModel, which would be classified as a Model under the MVC configuration. Unfortunately this value transference part is not working.

I then have UInfoRetrieveModel pass these 4 values directly to another Model called UserInfo which then delegates out any of these values to other view controllers on the UI side that may need them displayed. I have figured out how to pass values from UInfoRetrieveModel to UserInfo and from UserInfo (which is a model) to said view controllers but I have not figured out how to pass from a view controller, specifically CreateNewAccount, to a model, which in this case is UInfoRetrieveModel.

Basically my idea here is to have two model classes: one model that receives (UInfoRetrieveModel) and one that delegates out (UserInfo) the data values set in CreateNewAccount, in order to make the transference of data across the UI more efficient.

Below is my code for CreateNewAccount and UInfoRetrieveModel, where the transference seems to not be working:

UInfoRetrieveModel->

```
import Foundation

protocol UInfoRetrieveModelDelegate: class {
     func credentialTransfer(data:String)
}

class UInfoRetrieveModel: NSObject {

weak var delegate: UInfoRetrieveModelDelegate?

var firstName: String = ""
var lastName: String = ""
var userName: String = ""
var password: String = ""

func retrieving(){

    delegate?.credentialTransfer(data: firstName)
    delegate?.credentialTransfer(data: lastName)
    delegate?.credentialTransfer(data: userName)
    delegate?.credentialTransfer(data: password)
  }
}
```

CreateNewAccount->

```
import UIKit

class CreateNewAccount: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var FNInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var LNInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordInput: UITextField!

var uInfoRetrieve = UInfoRetrieveModel()

@IBAction func thanksForJoining(_ sender: Any) {
    uInfoRetrieve.firstName = FNInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.lastName = LNInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.userName = usernameInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.password = passwordInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.retrieving()        
    uInfoRetrieve.delegate = self
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
 }

extension CreateNewAccount: UInfoRetrieveModelDelegate{
   func credentialTransfer(data: String) {
      print(data)
   }
 }
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is happening and what should be happening. [Edit] your question with relevant details.

Comment: If thanksForJoining is called from a button press, then uInfoRetrieve should contain the values after pressing it. You are not seeing any prints because no one is calling retrieving() as far as I can see.

Comment: @rmaddy I edited my explanation of the issue

Comment: @ErikZivkovic I tried adding retrieving() in and I'm still not getting the data transference across

Comment: @ElanKainen did my answer below work for you? If so, please give it +1 and approve it, otherwise please leave a comment that it did not work. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikZivkovic i am unable to give it a +1 because I have a "reputation" of less than 15, but I just approved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `retrieving()` in the wrong order. Use this order instead:

```
@IBAction func thanksForJoining(_ sender: Any) {
    uInfoRetrieve.firstName = FNInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.lastName = LNInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.userName = usernameInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.password = passwordInput.text!
    uInfoRetrieve.delegate = self
    uInfoRetrieve.retrieving()        
}
```

Reason: If you call `retreiving()` before setting the delegate, the delegate will be `nil` and you won't get the callback.